# Why do I get ORA:0922 error:missing or invalid option

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Whats wrong with the following procedure?? I have checked the code for syntax errors but I m unable to find one.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Edit_premium_amt
    (
      policy_number IN number(4),
      new_premium_type  IN varchar2(4)
    )

    IS

    discount_amount number(6,2);
    premium_amts    number(11,2);
    policy_amts     number(11);
    dur             number(5);
    prem_type       varchar2(4);
    disc_weigh      varchar2(2);
    disc_perc       number(2);
    prem_type_int   number(2,1);

    BEGIN

    prem_type:=new_premium_type;

    UPDATE policy SET premium_type=new_premium_type WHERE policy_id=policy_number;

    SELECT policy_amt,duration INTO policy_amts,dur WHERE policy_id=policy_number;

    SELECT disc_weightage INTO disc_weigh FROM disc_details WHERE duration=dur;

    SELECT percent INTO disc_perc FROM disc_calculation WHERE premium_type=prem_type AND 

    weightage=disc_weigh;

    CASE prem_type

        WHEN 'HY' THEN prem_type_int:=2.0;
        WHEN 'Y' THEN prem_type_int:=1.0;

    ELSE  prem_type_int:=0.5;
    END CASE;

    discount_amount:= ((policy_amts)/dur)/prem_type_int))*disc_perc;

    premium_amts:=policy_amts-discount_amount;

    UPDATE policy SET premium_amt=premium_amts
    WHERE policy_id=policy_number;

END Edit_premium_amt;
```

Comment: `weightage=disc_weigh;` is not an assignment, it's an equality test. You've forgotten a semi-colon. P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow. When posting, can you always please include the _full_ error. Oracle should have given you a line-number which would identify this error.

Comment: I meant colon above... Also, looking at it you don't need semi-colons to end the THEN clauses of your CASE statement.

Comment: I have corrected that semicolon.But I still get the same error.And I m getting this as final error  "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"..     Its not giving any line numbers.Please tell me if there is any way to enable that in the error messgage. I m using oracle 10g XE.

Comment: weightage=disc_weigh; It is actually a comparision only not assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must say what you are creating or replacing

In this case `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Edit_premium_amt............`

Comment: Its a create statement.But I have been using the same syntax. i.e. create or replace.

Comment: SELECT policy_amt,duration INTO policy_amts,dur WHERE policy_id=policy_number; doesnt have a where clause..    got the solution